# Graph API - "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had Facebook integration working fine in my app until I updated my phones software version and Xcode. Now, whenever I run the app, I am greeted with the following error message. Anyone have any ideas?

```
    2012-05-30 00:23:49.680 [417:707] FACEBOOK FAILED!
2012-05-30 00:23:49.684 [417:707] REQUEST: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x2cbb30 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x2cb220 [0x3f9e2650]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x2cb140 [0x3f9e2650]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x2cb680 [0x3f9e2650]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x2cb620 [0x3f9e2650]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x2cb580 [0x3f9e2650]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
    6 : <CFString 0x2cba30 [0x3f9e2650]>{contents = "code"} = 2500
}
```

Comment: Are you using the newest Facebook SDK? Check your auth flow against the docs and make sure you're not forgetting to refresh the user's access token

Comment: I'm using the one i've always been using, so no, I haven't updated it in a while. Where would I get the current version info? I appreciate the help, but i'm pretty new to all of this. What's an auth flow and how do I check it?

Comment: There's no version info exactly, but it's possible that older copies of the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) don't play well with the newest iOS versions - the docs for implementing authentication are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ - adding this as a comment because i'm not sure this is definitely the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's likely that it would be something to do with that as nothing else has changed. I haven't touched the code at all. Do I simply replace the old files with the newest version?

Comment: I don't develop for iOS so i'm not sure what changes may need to be made other than replacing the old SDK with the new one, i recommend backing up the project before doing so, just in case

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update the Facebook Graph API to work with the new iOS version.